# How to force keyboard shortcut on chrome extension at install

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard

I'm trying to implement a chrome extension firing a event with a keyboard shortcut.

The shortcut is declared here :

```
    "commands":{
    "sample":{
        "suggested_key" : {
            "default":"Ctrl+I",
            "windows":"Ctrl+I"
        },
        "description":"Refresh display",
        "global": true
    }
}
```

All seems legit, but the problem is that I must set my keyboard shortcut manually in the "Keyboard shortcut" Chrome's menu.

I must force this at extension's installation without setting it manually. This extension will be used my automatsand they can't set this manually.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your description is *not* valid, and that's why it does not get assigned automatically.

Regarding global shortcuts [from documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands):

> The user is free to designate any shortcut as global using the UI in `chrome://extensions` \ Keyboard Shortcuts, but the extension developer is limited to specifying only `Ctrl+Shift+[0..9]` as global shortcuts.

In short, you can't do that; you need to change the shortcut used or make it non-global.

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2018 things changed in Chrome/Chromium and to change/assign shortcuts manually to extensions you have to use the following URL:

```
chrome://extensions/shortcuts
```

Also for makers of extensions the JSON changed a bit and they need to add the shortcuts in [`manifest.json`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest),   `manifest-GC.json`, `manifest-MF.json` like this:

```
"commands": { "execute_action": { "description": "Save Page", "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+S" } },
                  "save_page": { "description": "Save Page", "suggested_key": { "default": "Alt+Down" } }
                }
```

Comment: Protip: start your command names with numbers, like `"10_save_page"`, `"20_close_page"`, etc. if you want them to appear in a certain order in the shortcuts page, since they're sorted alphabetically). Use two digits so you can add more commands in between in the future, if needed (I started with `1_` and only later realized I wanted one before that. `0_` works, but it starts to get ugly after that.)

Answer (score 0):

[@Eduard Florinescu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51018668) is generally true, but note that one can't ***unset*** a shortcut if the extension sets a default. This is likely an [issue with Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1275357).