# Chrome Command API is not working for Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

In my manifest.json I am trying to open a new tab when I press "CTRL+SHIFT+Z" but the background.js file does not even log the event.

```
"toggle-feature-foo":{
  "suggested_key":{
    "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Z"
  },
  "description": "Toggle feature foo",
  "global": true
}
```

I have a listener in my background.js but nothing logs in my background.js console.

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener((command) => {
  console.log("HELLO");
  console.log(`Command: ${command}`);
});
```

I am following the API documentation from google: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/

Comment: Do you see the command if you go to: chrome://extensions/shortcuts ?

Comment: Yes I do and I have the listener in background.js. When I inspect the background.js console nothing prints when I input the shortcut

Comment: does it work if you remove global? Also if you are on a macOS, press command instead of ctrl. It only works for me after these two adjustments.

Comment: I initially had it without description and global and it didn't work. I am on Windows

Comment: @Neea ok it works but the problem was that the shortcut was not set automatically by the manifest file. I had to manually set it to CTRL+SHIFT+Z in the shortcuts page

Comment: Yes, I can only get it to set if I omit global. In the settings I can override it with anything manually including making it global. It seems to be a bug in chrome (also not the first time the docs are incorrect). My only suggestion is to educate the user they can set this command in the settings?

Comment: Thanks it works now, it seems that if we want to have a forced shortcut be global it has to be CTRL+SHIFT + [0...9] as shown in this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508095/how-to-force-keyboard-shortcut-on-chrome-extension-at-install

Comment: OK glad you figured it out. perhaps this should marked as duplicate since answer already exists.